# typing double apostrophe when apostrophe button is pressed

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, regional-settings

As the title explains, when I press the apostrophe button on my laptop (') it appears double. I am also unable to make an "é" directly by pushing the (') button followed by the "e". Which I would like.

Regional settings are English (United States)

Keyboard: United States-International

Windows 10 Home, HP Elitebook 745 G2, bought in the Netherlands with (i think) international keyboard.

Can someone help me out which settings to alter?

Comment: Have you tried to change your keyboard region to the region who's characters you wish to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no way to do an (é) in the American Keyboard, since US doesn't use the orthographic accent, in the sentences. But you can use it changing the input language of the keyboard in the Control Panel, to an Spanish layout.

Is this your keyboard? 
http://us-keyboard.net/images/740%20G1%20745%20G2%20750%20G1%20750%20G1.JPG

Could you please clarify and give us and example, in how is it come "double" when you press the apostrophe (') ?

Comment: Adding the Dutch language (Netherlands) with US-international keyboard did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

#### Can someone help me out which settings to alter?

You have an International keyboard layout set for your keyboard:

- With this keyboard layout the <kbd>'</kbd> keystroke becomes a modifier to enable entering of special characters.
- To get a single <kbd>'</kbd> character you need to type <kbd>'</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.
- To get a character like <kbd>é</kbd> you need to press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>.

If you want <kbd>'</kbd> to have the normal behavior change the keyboard layout to the appropriate non-international version.

- You will then have to use an alternate method to input <kbd>é</kbd>

See [How to Change Your Keyboard Layout in Windows 8 or 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/121169/how-to-change-your-keyboard-layout-in-windows-8/) for more information.

---

> Type International and Special Characters using the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key or the following modifier keys: Apostrophe(<kbd>'</kbd>), Accent Grave(<kbd>`</kbd>), Quotation Mark(<kbd>"</kbd>), Tilde(<kbd>~</kbd>), and Circumflex(<kbd>^</kbd>). To type just the modifier key by itself, type <kbd>Space</kbd> following the modifier key.

...

```
á é í ó ú     <Right Alt> a e i o u    Acute
Á É Í Ó Ú     <Right Alt> A E I O U
```

Source [Microsoft Keyboards - English (US-International)
Typing Diacritics And Special Characters](http://www.forlang.wsu.edu/help/keyboards1.asp)

Answer (score 0):

For window 8.1, at right side>>click on language>>keyboard popup will appear, click on "language Preference" (in red color)>>by default US keyboard-US International would be selected, now "click on option">>delete all keyboard>>add an input, select US keyboard only, save>>again click on add an input "select English(India) keyboard and save.

Problem solved. It's working.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.